# Ungrounded Simulated Inductor

Tags: operational-amplifier, inductor, ground

Is there a way to make an ungrounded simulated inductor? 
The figure below shows a grounded simulated inductor. I was wondering if this circuit could be altered to simulate an ungrounded inductor. 
[image]

Comment: Every circuit needs a ground. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @EasyOhm Instead of a ground, another node so there would be an inductor across two nodes like the left side of this. [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwireless-square.com%2F2016%2F11%2F04%2Fz-parameters-of-the-coupled-inductors-network%2F&psig=AOvVaw3rgCPUI61rsuHFq5gSNcyn&ust=1591238987754000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPDVyKjR5OkCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

Comment: Yes you can still make that in LTSpice just put whatever nodes you want on either side of it. You still need GND somewhere in the circuit tho.

Comment: Sej: the Google search term you want  to use is “floating” simulated inductor. You will find many solutions.

Comment: @user69795 Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Turns out I was looking for a 'floating' simulated inductor, or a floating synthetic inductor.