# Floating Simulated Inductor

Tags: operational-amplifier, inductor, floating, simulated

In the image below, I do understand that a grounded inductor can be simulated using op amps. However, to make a floating simulated inductor, I have read some posts that said two ground simulated inductors must be connected back to back. I am not sure why they should be connected back to back, as shown in the bottom diagram. Why must they be connected back to back?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You posted a [very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503369/ungrounded-simulated-inductor) yesterday. If you don't get answers to your question, we ask you to improve the question by editing it, not re-post it.

Comment: Here you can find a simpler version: 1- Grounded inductor https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/3464261900_1482234787.gif and the floating one https://youtu.be/AEJtajaRj_s?t=289 the same https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/VLjqXUaALOykVh9F-m5J9HIf2fn2hT5pnhcWHNSfC9BJ0h3NUQfrHWJP-osflZW8c6aVHtAPNM3yLKWg6A3ia9MW_jv5gsGgkY0WGlKeEmhDjLB2ZR8=w472

Comment: While they are not exact duplicates (they are different questions on the same topic), @SEJ you should go and answer your question (because you found a floating inductor).

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thanks for the reminder. Though I'm not exactly sure how to accept comments as answered, I edited the title. I'm sorry I'm not very used to the stackoverflow community. I've only just made an account. Thank you for helping me adapt.

Comment: @ThePhoton I did indeed post that question, which led to this question. Yes, I found out that the term I was trying to find was 'floating' simulated inductor, which was very helpfully answered. However, I thought editing the entire question to asking why two ground simulated inductors need to be connected back to back to simulate a floating inductor would be too much of a change. Thank you for the suggestion though, I'm still getting used to this blessed community. (edit: spelling)

Comment: You can't accept a comment as an answer. You can either ask the commentor to post their comment as an answer, or post your own answer giving more detail than was in the comment. 24 hours later you'll be able to "accept" your own answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for the tip! I've posted an 'answer' and I will 'accept' it tomorrow!

Comment: @G36 Thank you for the reply. I looked at the video, and the man says 'I looked at it, and why not take two of 'em!'. I'm not exactly sure why taking 'two of 'em' can make a floating synthetic inductor.

Comment: @SEJ, you can actually write your own answers if you find the answer to your question, the object of SE its to make a repository for questions and answers.